# All commands of the same method are not being executed

Tags: android, xml, android-handler

Two things are supposed to happen inside the following method. The `ProgressBar` is supposed to be set to 100% and a layout is supposed to be visible. But on calling the method, the layout gets visible but the `ProgressBar` does not change its value.

I must add that this is a file sharing app and the `ProgressBar` becomes 100% on the client side of the code, the problem is on the server. Although both the codes are the same.

```
ServerClass_Activity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue(100);
        mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle("100%");
        meowLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

There is a handler running that updates the `ProgressBar` for a certain time.

```
Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Log.d( "","entered run ");
            mWaveLoadingView.setCenterTitle(String.valueOf(progress)+"%");
            mWaveLoadingView.setProgressValue(progress);
            progress+=1;

            if(progress==90 || finished == true)
                stopRepeatingTask();

        } finally {
            if(progress<90 && finished == false)
                mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, mInterval);
        }
    }
};
```

The variable `finished` becomes `true` when the file is sent successfully.
Any idea why the `ProgressBar` is not being 100%?

Comment: if the layout gets visible by the first code. then there is no way that the setProgress of the progress bar does not work\

Comment: @seyedJafari exactly my point. This is not supposed to happen but somehow it is